# X-bar theory without movement

Tags: dependency-grammar, x-bar-theory, movement

Are there any theories out there that use X-bar theory but deny movement (like Dependency Syntax can)?

Comment: "Use X-bar theory" is pretty vague.  You mean does the "bar" notation ever turn up?  GPSG, which denies movement, has bar-level as a feature of some categories.

Comment: Same for LFG. On the configurational extreme of the configurationality scale in LFG (e.g. in English), all phrases have bar levels.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look at LFG, they use X' Theory extended with an additional "lexocentric" category S to accommodate nonconfigurational phrase structures.

Answer (score 1):

To my mind, the canonical "generative but non-derivational" work is the stuff that Michael Brody did.

Have a look at his book *Lexico-Logical Form*, which is a great and detailed exploration of an alternative approach to "minimalism", and after that find his work on "Mirror Syntax" (I think it appeared in *Linguistic Inquiry* circa 2000).